# document get element by id возвращает null

Tags: javascript, html, css

html

```
<p id="encode-span">aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

js

```
const encode = document.getElementById('encode-span').value;
console.log(encode);
```

Comment: `innerHTML` либо `textContent`, `innerText` вместо `value`

Comment: все тоже самое все пробовал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых у вас возможно ещё не прогрузился DOM и поэтому на момент срабатывания метода такого элемента ещё нет на странице. Поэтому надо попробовать сделать это **после** загрузки страницы.

Во-вторых у `p` нет атрибута `value`, но есть `textContent` и `innerHTML`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

function ready() {
    const encode = document.getElementById('encode-span').textContent;
    console.log(encode);
}
```

```html
<p id="encode-span">aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

Comment: По поводу прогркзки Dom - во время публикации ответов тут всегда вверху отображается js-код, а уже ниже - html. Я даже однажды опубликовал в правильной последовательности, только все а одном поле html, так после этого кто-то сделал правку в два разных поля, и js оказался наверху.

Comment: @Опан просто тут есть своя песочница и сниппеты, где можно воспроизвести проблему или пример (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). И по правилам желательно прикладывать этот самый пример. В случае неполной прогрузки ДОМ такое не сработает, но те кто знает - уже как правило понимает в чём может быть проблема)