# Как правильно прописать функцию во внешнем JS, вызываемую через onclick с html

Tags: javascript

Имеется кнопка для музыки, которая будет включать и выключать ее. Был скрипт в самом html и все работало, но для внешнего файла js нужно его переделывать. Попробовал изменить, но выдает такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код (пишу в adobe dreamweaver, но она не сообщает о проблеме):

```js
function ChangeM(){   
document.getElementById("MyBut").innerHTML = "myaudio"
    
var myaudio = this.getAttribute("myaudio"); 
      if(myaudio.paused == true)
      {
        document.getElementById("myaudio").play();
             }
      else if (myaudio.paused == false)
      {
        document.getElementById("myaudio").pause();
      }
}
ChangeM();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/Main.js"></script>  
</head> 
<body>

<div>
            
<button class="MusBut" id="MyBut" type="button" onclick="ChangeM()" >Click</button>
            
 <audio id="myaudio"> <source src="snd/erik-satie-gymnopedie-no-1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
 </audio>
                        
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function ChangeM(el) {
              // ^-----Добавить
  document.getElementById("MyBut").innerHTML = "myaudio"

  var myaudio = el.getAttribute("myaudio");
              // ^------------ Заменить
  if (myaudio.paused == true) {
    document.getElementById("myaudio").play();
  } else if (myaudio.paused == false) {
    document.getElementById("myaudio").pause();
  }
}

document.getElementById('MyBut').click();
//ChangeM(); ---Удалить
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/Main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>

    <button class="MusBut" id="MyBut" type="button" onclick="ChangeM(this)" myaudio="true">Click</button>
    <!-- Тут тоже пара изменений -->

    <audio id="myaudio"> <source src="snd/erik-satie-gymnopedie-no-1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
 </audio>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Теперь такая ошибка в js-файле:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null at Main.js:16

Comment: @Icaab надо выполнять всё это значит после загрузки dom https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1273335/191482

Comment: Я сам еще плохо разбираюсь в JS. Может вас неправильно понял, но сейчас задействовал разные варианты,чтоб функция выполнялась после загрузки DOM, но ошибок становится только больше
[Img](https://ibb.co/mTx8JZH)

Comment: @Icaab надо в колбэке DOMContentLoaded  выполнить строку `document.getElementById('MyBut').click();` чтобы именно сам поиск элемента и клик по нему происходил после загрузки.

Comment: Думаю понял, что вы имели в виду. Переписал код, добавив выполнение и ошибка исчезла, но аудио так же не работает (само audio включается, если autoplay приписать, но не вырубается - само собой).  Что-то злая кнопка отказывается сдаваться)
А можете попробовать со своей любой песней проверить работоспособность?
https://jsfiddle.net/7012wst8/

Comment: @Icaab попробуйте вместо `var myaudio = el.getAttribute("myaudio");` написать `var myaudio = document.getElementById("myaudio");`  тогда все `el` и `this` даже уже не нужны

Comment: Да, изменения звука заработало.
Извините, немного смещу тему:
Мне помимо остановки музыки нужно и картинку менять в кнопке. Прописал по схожему принципу и поменял ее свойства, чтоб обращаться к другому id для смены изображения, но браузер не видит этот id (хотя пути указаны верно):
https://jsfiddle.net/8fd0hrv5/

Comment: @Icaab лучше создайте новый вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Подключите ваш .js файл перед закрывающим тегом body.
Или же добавьте атрибут "defer".

```html
<script src="js/Main.js" defer></script>
```