# При загрузке страницы добавлять в input случайные числа

Tags: javascript

Можно ли каждый раз при загрузке страницы добавлять в `input` (в моем случае перед `1@gmail.com`) случайные (рандомные) любые цифры, что бы они не повторялись? Такое решение мне нужно для того, что бы в дальнейшем в моей форме регистрации при нажатии на кнопку каждому пользователю гененрировался уникальный email.

```
<input class="textfield wpuf_user_email_11800" id="user_email_11800" type="email" data-required="no" data-type="text" name="user_email" placeholder="" value="1@gmail.com" size="40">
```

Я нашла такой скрипт, но не пойму как мне вставить генерируемое число в `value` и поставить после генерируемого числа `1@gmail.com`

```
function getRandom(min, max){
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
document.getElementById('user_email_11800').innerHTML = getRandom(500,1500000);
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` — у input нет innerHTML. Код заработает, если заменить его на `.value` Опять же, уникальность не гарантируется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.user-email').value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + '@gmail.com';
```

```html
<input class="textfield wpuf_user_email_11800 user-email" id="user_email_11800" type="email" data-required="no" data-type="text" name="user_email" placeholder="" value="1@gmail.com" size="40"/>
```

Однако

> при нажатии на кнопку каждому пользователю гененрировался уникальный email.

не получится в любом случае. Потому что данные юзера должны улетать на сервер и сохранятся в БД. А клиентская часть ничего не знает про БД. И в итоге в какой-то момент сгенерируется число, которое уже есть в БД и вставка не удастся. Этот код придётся либо сравнивать со всей кучей email уже имеющихся в БД, либо перенести генерацию на серверную часть.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в консоле показывает ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: @АннаМатвеева "в консоли"

Comment: @АннаМатвеева потому что JS выполняется до того, как прогрузился DOM  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1273335/191482